# Can I create a Billing Agreement with credit card (without paypal account)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

As per the subject. Does my customer MUST to have paypal account and login to his paypal account in order for me to create a billing agreement, or I can use credit card as payment method for a billing agreement?

I am working with REST Api

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible.

An example of the API is here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/BillingAgreementWithCreditCard.aspx.cs

Subscriptions (recurring payments) option for direct payments needs to be also enabled in merchant paypal account. I had trouble with it but messaged paypal and they enabled the feature for us.

So tested and working now.