# Authorize a PayPal billing that doesn't expire

Tags: paypal

I'd need to get and store users auth to bill them via PayPal in the future, the auth shouldn't expire.

The normal auth & capture lasts 29 days. So I looked into subscription and/or recurring payments but here you need to specify how many times, how often and for how long you want to charge.

What I need is the possibility to charge user's PayPal account when something happen (never, tomorrow, in 3 months, once or twice etc) without asking the user to login/auth it again.
Many sites do this (for example godaddy charges me when one of my domains expire or when I buy a new one) but can't find the documentation.

Comment: you can charge a customer whenever required, but you have to partner with paypal. its called billing agreement.
https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/partner-programme

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, this is called [billing agreement](https://www.paypal.com/uk/smarthelp/article/what-is-a-billing-agreement-and-how-does-it-work-faq1848):

> A Billing Agreement allows a seller to charge your PayPal account when you purchase goods from them or use their service.
>
> An example of this would be an agreement to pay eBay seller fees for listing items on eBay
>
> Billing Agreements are different from subscriptions. With subscriptions, a fixed amount is charged for a specified period, but with Billing Agreements, the amount and time period aren't fixed.

This feature probably must be activated in your merchant Paypal account.

Here is a related question: [Can I create a Billing Agreement with credit card (without paypal account)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455504/can-i-create-a-billing-agreement-with-credit-card-without-paypal-account)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it is called billing agreement (and this is a step forward) but can't find docs about it. It looks like paypal hides it

Comment: You can look at the [BillingAgreementTestCase.java](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/1ef1baad8728f49e0dd6a913d2d455826423b1a6/rest-api-sdk/src/test/java/com/paypal/api/payments/BillingAgreementTestCase.java). There is equivalent for other languages too.